# How to set up the end points in unit test for the self hosted wcf service?

Tags: c#

I've followed the advice on this forum and create a unit test to test for the connectivity for my self hosted wcf. It is that to create a service host in my test (self-hosted) and load my service. After that, I can set up my end points  and connect the client to the server. However, that approach would work with simple HTTP and WSHTTP while mine is NetTcp. How would I set up the end points for the NetTcp ?This is what I've been working so far:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1 :ISimSession
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ServiceHost host = null;
            try
            {
                var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextGenService/SimSession/");
                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimSession), baseAddress);
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                var address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextGenService/SimSession/");

                var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(SimSession), binding, address.Uri);
                var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true };
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                using(var client = ???? )
                {
                    endpoint.Name = client.Endpoint.Name;
                    host.Open();
                }

                host.Close(); 



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //...tests

            }
            finally
            {
                if(host != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)host).Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
}
```